# How to see google group when subscribed with an alias?

Tags: gmail, alias, google-groups

An administrator add my mail address to a private google group (mailing list).

I correctly received the mail notifying that I am subscribed to this group with a link to view old post in this group.

But my address contains an alias (example : `firstname.lastname+alias@gmail`) and when I follow the link, Google group tell me that I am not subscribed to this group.

I think that all is about the alias, but how to see old mail from this group ?

PS : I don't want to ask for subcribing with my mail address without alias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to access the group archive when the Gmail alias + address is subscribed.

You can email the group owner(s) by sending an email to groupname+owners@googlegroups.com.

Comment: I said in the question I don't want to ask for subcribing with my mail address without alias.
All the question is in this problem : How to access the group with the alias ?

Comment: Then the answer is "you can't". You'll need to get the correct normal address added to the group. You can keep both of them added and turn mail flow off for the real address if you prefer.

Comment: The alias address is "correct" even if it is not "normal". How not google mail user can see private group archive ? Can't they ? Isn't there a command to the group bot to ask for a url token to be able to see it ? I am disappointed that there is no solution for such a problem (by the way, if you create or edit your answer to say it is not possible, I will accept it)